# Conversion of integer division to double

Tags: java

I want the help to produce the result of below calculation as 1.12 but the result is coming up 1.0
`double k=(112)/100;
System.out.println(k);`

Comment: use double k-=((double)112/100)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `Integer division` causing it to lose the precision:

Replace

`double k=(112)/100;`

with

`double k=(112.0)/100;`

Answer (score 0):

`double k-=((double)112/100)` worked for me as suggested by agni

when we do division like (112/100) JVM gives int as an o/p, you are storing that 'int' in 'double' so JVM adds '.0' to the o/p causing loss of precision. so, here you have to tell the JVM to give o/p without any loss. for that reason we have to mention like `double k = (double)112/100; which is similar to "typecasting".